# Assembly Versioning

Tags: c#, msbuild, azure-pipelines

How can I achieve assembly versioning?Suppose I have a solution containing different project.I want to put same assemblyVersion Number to all these projects.When I commit this solution to Visual studio online and build using MSBuild,I want to get assembly version number in a sequence.

For Example,
Initial build,Assembly version number will be 1.1.0.1
Second build,It will be 1.1.0.2
So on,

The main purpose of this question is: I want to tag each build with a specific number,So if there is some issue,I can easily identify the build using this unique number.

Comment: The [AssemblyVersion] is entirely too sacred to ever abuse it to store a build number.  Change the [AssemblyFileVersion] instead.  Either by hand or with a little utility started in a prebuild event that rewrites the file by incrementing the number.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to achieve,

Either use an assemblyversion of 1.0.1.* , this will auto increment for every Build solution. (NOTE, I'm not using this myself, so behaviour may have changed).

I create a Version.cs file which in a pre-build step. 
This file is generated using a subwcrev, which replaces variables in a template with the last revision number for the solution from our svn server.
In this way we can link any version directly to a specific revision.